# Error correction : Our office building comprises seven floors and a restaurant at the top in an area of about eight hundred sq. meters

Tags: exam-questions

> Our office building comprises (A)/ seven floors and a restaurant at the top in an (B)/ area of about eight hundred sq. metres.(C)/ No error

I took an exam which had English comprehension as one of its section, today its provisional key came out. I marked the answer of above sentence as  No error but as per key the answer is B part. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in part B ? I think the answer of key is wrong, if it is I can submit representation for it.

Comment: I don't like "in" - is the restaurant in an area of 800sqm? Or is the building on a footprint of 800sqm? Or do the seven floors plus restaurant add up to 800sqm? It's ambiguous and doesn't really sound "right" to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm really sorry for not proof reading the post, that was a typo, I have updated it.

Comment: @user212388: Apart from that mistranscription there's nothing about your text that could usefully be identified as "erroneous". It's the kind of pointless test made up by incompetent teachers (often with little *real* knowledge of English) that I wouldn't bother with if I were you. Stylistically speaking, I might prefer ***within** an area...,* but because of the overall structure there's always going to be ambiguity as to whether those 800 sq. m represent the entire building, the subsection used by the company, or just the restaurant (unless you do some wholesale rephrasing).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Someone suggested "on" the top , Does it hold water ?

Comment: You could make any number of minor changes (*consists of* instead of *comprises*, *on [the] top* instead of *at the top*, discard *of* after *area*, etc.). But these are all stylistic choices that have no real significance.

Comment: @user212388  *at* or *on* the top, either is fine.  I agree with FumbleFingers -- while "in an area of ..." is probably a little strange, overall this kind of test question is designed to be deliberately difficult, so that few students will get it correct.  It has almost nothing to do with how English is *naturally spoken*.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

> Our office building comprises seven floors **with** a restaurant at the top, in an area of about eight hundred sq. metres.

I wouldn't use a conjunction because *floors* and *restaurant* are not similar items.
I added the comma for clarity but it is optional.

I have to agree that B is the problem.